# How to use FINDSTR to strip lines with % from robocopy logfile?

Tags: special-characters, robocopy, findstr

I would like to strip all the lines with a % progress-value from my robocopy logfiles. The lines look like this:

```
           *EXTRA Datei            7.3 g    test.pst
             Neuer                 7.3 g    huge.PST
  0.0%
  0.0%
  0.0%
  0.1%
  0.1%
  0.1%
  0.1%
 99.8%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
100%  
             Neue Datei            7.5 g    another.PST
  0.0%
```

I'm not successful with this attempt

```
FINDSTR.exe /V "%" LogFile.txt > LogFileWithoutPercentageLines.txt
```

because this cuts too much lines away (in the above example the entire line with `huge.PST` and `another.PST`)

The %-lines includes two spaces before 0.0% and a CR.
The %-lines includes one space before 10.0% and a CR.
The %-line includes no space before 100.0% but two spaces after 100% and a CR.

How can I get rid of this useless 0.0% until 100% lines only with FINDSTR?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`robocopy` with `/NP` switch](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), cf *Logging Options* in `robocopy /?`:

> ```
> /NP :: No Progress - don't display percentage copied.
> ```

For instance, `robocopy "%_source%" "%_target%" /log:"%temp%\38610436.log" /NP`

However, next **commented script** shows a possible way of removing all that unwanted progress stuff from an existing *weed-infested* log file (`findstr` itself does not suffice for this complex task):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_source=d:\bat\odds and ends\B"        rem change to match your circumstances
set "_target=d:\bat\odds and ends\Bcopy"    rem detto
set "_logFileRawData=%temp%\38610436.log"   rem detto
set "_logFileCleaned=%temp%\38610436a.log"  rem detto

rem /NP : No Progress - don’t display % copied
rem robocopy "%_source%" "%_target%" /log:"%temp%\38610436.log" /NP
    robocopy "%_source%" "%_target%" /log:"%temp%\38610436.log"

>"%_logFileCleaned%" (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%G in ( `findstr /N "^" "%_logFileRaw%"` ) do (
    set "_line=%%H"
    call :strip_Progress
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
      echo(!_line!
    ENDLOCAL
  )
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:strip_Progress
set "_zero="                      rem zero percent indicator
set "_line=%_line%"               rem remove all Carriage Return characters
  rem after above command, _line with progress could be, excluding Square Brackets:
    rem [New File              0    ZeroFile.ext100%  ]
    rem [New File          51808    TinyFile.txt  0%  100%  ]
    rem [Newer             1.1 m    Mid_File.ext  0%   21%   42%   64%   85%  100%  ]
    rem [New File        162.1 m    Big_File.ext  0.0%  0.6%  1.2% … 99.3% 99.9%100%  ]
if "%_line%"=="" goto :eof
if "%_line:~-6%"=="100%%  " call :removeProgress
goto :eof

:removeProgress
set "_line=%_line:~0,-6%"         rem strip six trailing characters
if defined _zero goto :eof
    rem as yet, zero percent indicator not set
:stripTrailingSpace
if "%_line:~-2%"==" "  set "_line=%_line:~0,-1%" & goto :stripTrailingSpace
if "%_line:~-4%"=="  0%%"   set "_zero=4" & set "_line=%_line%x%%" 
if "%_line:~-6%"=="  0.0%%" set "_zero=6"
if "%_line:~-1%"=="%%" goto :removeProgress
goto :eof
```

**Further resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%G`, `%H` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>`, `&` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`%_line:~0,-6%` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%%` doubled percent sign)  [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Just for the records: Executing robocopy without percent progress isn't an option in this case, because the user has to see a progress on screen for huge files like 7.5 GB *.pst. There is no way to use /NP for log only, AFAIK.